# Wordpress Sticky navbar when the admin bar is present

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, sticky

I used this sticky jQuery plugin in my site for the top navbar.
[jQuery Sticky](https://github.com/garand/sticky)

It works correctly, but when the WP admin bar is present that cover the top navbar.
I tried to dependency the stickiness to the admin bar:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){                                                        
    if ( $("#wpadminbar").length ) {
                $("#navbar").sticky({topSpacing:"28px"}); 
                    } else { $("#navbar").sticky({topSpacing:0});
                           }                                   
                 });
```

but this is immediately stuck the navbar to the top not only when scrolling. I appreciate any assistance. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to write something like scroll listener.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't call `.sticky` anywhere else? Also, Wordpress and some plug-ins may cause some dependency issues. I always use jQuery [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode in Wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't just adjust `navbar`'s `margin-top`?

I'm not using the `Sticky` plugin but I've a similar problem and the code below solve.

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // if adminbar exist (should check for visible?) then add margin to our navbar
        var $wpAdminBar = $('#wpadminbar');
        if ($wpAdminBar.length) {
            $('div.navbar').css('margin-top',$wpAdminBar.height()+'px');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. Yes, your solution is works, with a little modification. Thank you very much!

Comment: @agva, glad it worked, be aware that the `wpadminbar` (at least in 3.9) is responsive also (height change if the window become small), so you may need to `bind` the `window` `resize` event, and maybe the `scroll` too, good luck

Comment: For me, `#wpadminbar` height is always `undefined` ..yes, even while logged in. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final script in my case. Maybe it is will helpful for someone else.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){                                                             
        var $wpAdminBar = $('#wpadminbar');
        if ($wpAdminBar.length) {
        $("div.navbar").sticky({topSpacing:$wpAdminBar.height()});
        } else {
        $("div.navbar").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the admin bar from showing

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's less complicated than you're making it. if a person is logged in, you can test the body element for the "logged-in" class. Unless I'm missing something obvious, this works for me.

```
if($("body").hasClass("logged-in")) {
    $("#site-navigation").sticky({topSpacing: 28, className: "stickyNav"});
} else {
    $("#site-navigation").sticky({topSpacing: 0, className: "stickyNav"});
}
```

Comment: Maybe you right, but each users can disable the admin bar on the wordpress admin/user profile settings. So, in this case if the user disable it and logged in, the sticky is add the 28px to the top anyway, even if the admin bar is not present. Am I right?

Comment: You would be right. Funny, I had missing that setting up until now.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This is Fix CSS for WP Admin Bar */
@media screen and ( min-width: 601px ) {
    .logged-in.admin-bar #navbar-default.affix-top { margin-top: 31px !important; }
    .logged-in.admin-bar #navbar-default.affix { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    body.logged-in .navbar-default.affix{ top:32px }
    .navbar-default.affix{ width:100%;top:0px;z-index:999;border-radius:0;border:none }
}
@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) and ( min-width: 601px ) {
    .logged-in.admin-bar #navbar-default.affix-top { margin-top: 0px !important; }
    .logged-in.admin-bar #navbar-default.affix { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    .logged-in.admin-bar #xs-phone { margin-top: 45px !important; }
}
@media screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
    .logged-in.admin-bar #xs-phone { padding-top: 45px !important; }
    .navbar-default.affix{position: relative !important;}
}
```

and add in functions.php

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "28px" to 28, and it works for me,
or you can use this:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#wpadminbar").length) {
        $("#sticker-sticky").sticky({topSpacing:28});
    }else {
        $("#sticker-sticky").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest format that works:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        
    var $navbar = $("#masthead");
    var $wpAdminBar = $('#wpadminbar');
        
    $navbar.sticky({topSpacing:  $wpAdminBar.length? $wpAdminBar.height() : 0 });
    
});
```